# How to set the thousands place separator in pandas read_csv?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading a csv file like this:

```
import pandas as pd

arq_pedido = pd.read_csv('Pedido.csv',delimiter=";", encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

I have a ID column (this column is supposed to be an INT column, but in Brazil (Portuguese), thousand's numbers is represented like this: 1.000 instead of 1000.
So, my ID column is `dfloat64` at the moment.

I have one ID who is `1.908 (1908)`, and this number shows `1.9080000000000001.` How can I transform dfloat64 to int? Or, how can I replace dots (.) for comma (,), to turned that numbers in thousands ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `thousands` parameter for this. Try,

```
arq_pedido = pd.read_csv('Pedido.csv', delimiter=";", encoding = "ISO-8859-1", thousands=".")
```

You may also wish to set `decimal=","` to handle decimal numbers correcltly.

Answer (score 0):

The [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) method has parameters for just about every conceivable scenario.  You're probably interested in the `thousands` parameter for the thousands place separator, the `decimal` parameter for the decimal point, and the `sep` parameter for the column separator.

```
import pandas as pd
import io
foobar = io.StringIO("foo;bar \n 1,000; 2.0")
pd.read_csv(foobar, thousands=",", decimal=".", sep=";")
#    foo  bar 
#0  1000   2.0
```